# PowerShell Core `Select-Xml` Returns Nothing

Tags: powershell-core

I have an XML file I want to get value(s) from with PowerShell Core.

Cleaned up example:

```xml
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks></TargetFrameworks>
    <RootNamespace></RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName></AssemblyName>
    <Company></Company>
    <Authors></Authors>
    <Description></Description>
    <Copyright></Copyright>
    <AssemblyVersion></AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion></FileVersion>
    <Product></Product>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <RepositoryUrl></RepositoryUrl>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild></GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

I want to get the value of the `<Version>` element, which is `1.0.0`.

I run:

```
pwsh Select-Xml -Path test.csproj -XPath "//Version"
```

Which returns:

```
Node    Path                     Pattern
----    ----                     -------
Version D:\Downloads\test.csproj //Version
```

When I try to get the value as per Microsoft's docs, with:

```
pwsh Select-Xml -Path test.csproj -XPath "//Version" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node
```

I get the following error:

```
Select-Object : Property "Node" cannot be found.
At line:1 char:56
+ ... h test.csproj -XPath "//Version" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node
+                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:PSObject) [Select-Object], PSArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpandPropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand

Select-Object : Property "Node" cannot be found.
At line:1 char:56
+ ... h test.csproj -XPath "//Version" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node
+                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Node    Path                     Pattern:PSObject) [Select-Object], PSArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpandPropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand

Select-Object : Property "Node" cannot be found.
At line:1 char:56
+ ... h test.csproj -XPath "//Version" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node
+                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (----    ----                     -------:PSObject) [Select-Object], PSArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpandPropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand

Select-Object : Property "Node" cannot be found.
At line:1 char:56
+ ... h test.csproj -XPath "//Version" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node
+                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Version D:\Download\u2026st.csproj //Version:PSObject) [Select-Object], PSArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpandPropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand

Select-Object : Property "Node" cannot be found.
At line:1 char:56
+ ... h test.csproj -XPath "//Version" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node
+                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:PSObject) [Select-Object], PSArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpandPropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand
```

How do I get this XML element's value?

Answer (score 0):

Pwsh defaults to -file instead of -command.  There's also a quoting issue with the pipe symbol.  This works, assuming you're running it from cmd:

```
pwsh -c "Select-Xml //Version test.csproj | Select -Expand Node"

#text
-----
1.0.0
```

Or

```
pwsh -c (Select-Xml //Version test.csproj).node
```

If this is run from unix or other versions of powershell, there's different issues.

Comment: Getting `The term '-c' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`. This is for PowerShell Core? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-windows?view=powershell-6

Comment: This works for me from cmd.exe:  `pwsh -c 'hi there'` (version 6.2.3)

Comment: Strange. `pwsh -c 'hi there'` from cmd.exe gives me the same error; `The term '-c' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`.

Comment: `-command` gives the same error.`pwsh` shows the version as `PowerShell 6.2.3`. It was installed hours ago using the commands from Microsoft's docs posted in the comment above.

Comment: Microsoft's docs don't show `Command` as an existing module: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/?view=powershell-6

Comment: It’s a command line option.  I honestly don’t understand your question.